# What exactly is a ModuleWrapper in Python?

Tags: python, module

This may be the most basic question ever, but recently I'm trying to understand better what typing something like:

```
model = statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS(y, X).fit()
```

does exactly. Trying to understand the fundamentals that is, as opposed to going, well if I type that I can fit a linear least squares regression model, so I'll just type that each time I want it. So now I'm trying to understand it on a more thorough level. So I've started using the ? more and I find that:

statsmodels is the library

regression is the ModuleWrapper

linear_model is the module

OLS is the type/class

fit is the method associated with the instance of the OLS type

So my questions is this, what exactly is a ModuleWrapper? I can't believe I couldn't find an answer to this through a search already, so sorry for that, but could it be as simple as it's just a bundle/wrapper of several different modules?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a generic Python thing. It must just be a class defined by your statsmodels library.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regression` is a folder or subdirectory of statsmodels with several modules

The full file path for the module that defines the OLS class is

`...\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py`

However, python does not require that paths correspond to actual directories, files or modules.

When using the api imports, `import statsmodels.api`, then the python path for accessing does not correspond to files on disk.

e.g. `statmodels\api.py` contains

`from .genmod.api import families, cov_struct`

and `...\statsmodels\genmod\api.py` contains the imports from the actual modules or subdirectories

```
from . import families
from . import cov_struct
```

For example, we can use the api shortcut to access the Poisson family, while the actual module that defines the class has a different and longer path.

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm

>>> sm.families.Poisson
<class 'statsmodels.genmod.families.family.Poisson'>
>>> sm.families.Poisson.__module__
'statsmodels.genmod.families.family'
```

The import directly from the module that contains the code for the Poisson family would be

```
>>> import statsmodels.genmod.families.family
>>> statsmodels.genmod.families.family.Poisson
<class 'statsmodels.genmod.families.family.Poisson'>
```

So sometimes names in the path refer to actual file paths, while in other cases it is the indirect import through intermediate modules and does not correspond to the actual directory structure.

A brief explanation why statsmodels uses this dual import structure is in http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/importpaths.html .

Comment: Thanks, answers the question and gives me some new learning to do as well. Much appreciated.